# Latex error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}

Tags: tables

I'm getting the following error from my Latex code:

`\begin{document}` ended by `\end{table}`

But the error is not what the message says, because the `begin{document}` is ended by `\end{document}`.
The problem is with the command `\begin{table}`, when I turn it in comment, the table works fine, but when I turn it on, the table disappear and the message appears.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Variância das séries}} \\
\hline
\hline
Dados originais & 0,01065676 \\
1ª diferença & 0,003638648 \\
\hline
\caption{Variância das séries}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

And these are the packages that I'm using

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{chngpage,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{conf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese, english, brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi Filipe, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As far as I can see, `\caption` is in the wrong place - move it outside the `tabular` environment. You can also use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. `:)`

Answer (score 14):

The error you mentioned is actually the last error in the compilation process and comes as a consequence of this one:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.27 \caption{Variância das séries}
```

`\caption` is in the wrong place, we need to move it outside the `tabular` environment. A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Variância das séries}} \\
\hline
\hline
Dados originais & 0,01065676 \\
1ª diferença & 0,003638648 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Variância das séries}
\label{tab:varianciaseries}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Note that I added a `\label{tab:varianciaseries}` to the code, so you can refer to this table later in the document by simply using it:

```
De acordo com a Tabela~\ref{tab:varianciaseries}, ...
```

Hope it helps. `:)`